# Is it possible to hide the action bar in a Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hide

I have a Linear Layout with an action bar on top of it. Bellow it there are some buttons and a Relative layout with some data. I want to know is it possible to hide the action bar while scrolling in through the data just like in Chrome? Scroll down the action bar hides scroll up and it appears.

here is the XML code of the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#353535"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```

z

```
        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:contentDescription="ZONA"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabZoneHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_zone"
            android:gravity="center"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="VISITADAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabVisitedHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_visited"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="SUGERENCIAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabSuggestionsHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_suggestions"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_detailholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/quickview_top_gradient"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/an-emerging-ui-pattern-quick-return.html) has an useful pattern which can be used to achieve this. The link also has a [sample code reference](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks#scrolltricks%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexample%2Fandroid), you can refer that for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActionBar.hide()`